# Configure Spring security for Angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-security

I'm building a Angular 2 web client that tries to do a POST to a server using SpringBoot Security. How should I write my Spring security configuration?

My Angular call for authentication:

```ts
public login(username, password) {
  let body = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password});
  let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
  this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/login", body, options)
    .subscribe(
      res => this.loggedIn = true,
      err => console.error("failed authentication: " + err),
      () => console.log("tried authentication")
    );
}
```

The authentication fails with the error:

> {"timestamp":1487007177889,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication Failed: Empty Username","path":"/login"}

My spring security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    
    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationFailureHandler restAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RestLogoutSuccessHandler restLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)

                .and().formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()

                .and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(restLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll()

                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        // This configuration has been tested, it works.
        // It has been removed for better readability
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        // This configuration has been tested, it works.
        // It has been removed for better readability
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a Spring issue. I see nothing wrong in your Angular code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters for form login, not JSON. That's why the error is saying that the username is missing, because Spring Security it trying to get it from the HttpServletRequest#getParameters. To send form parameters in Angular, you can do

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('username', username);
params.set('password', password);
```

If you set it as the body parameter of the Http request, it *should* (from what I remember) automatically be serialized to the correct format, i.e.

```
username=xxx&password=xxx
```

And I don't think you need to set the header `Content-Type` to `applicatio/x-www-form-urlencoded` either. I think that should also be set for you when Angular detects `URLSearchParams` as the body.

Comment: That did the trick, many thanks.
Man `URLSearchParam`, what? How intuitive is that?

Comment: Well it's also used for query strings. I guess the name makes more sense for that

Comment: I did use `headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` in the end with the body `"username=" + username + "&password=" + password`. But I think I'll authenticate differently with something like Oauth 2 anyway.