# Bad Credentials response when using Spring Security in memory authentication

Tags: spring, angular, authentication, spring-security

I have configured my Java Spring backend to use in memory authentication but when I do a POST request through my angular2 frontend entering the right username/password in a login form, I always get the following errors:

> x POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate 401 ()    zone.js:1382
>
> x EXCEPTION: Response with status: 401 OK for URL: http://localhost:8080/authenticate     core.umd.js:3370
>
> x Uncaught Response {_body: "{"code":401,"message":"Authentication failed","err…reason":"authError","message":"Bad credentials"}}", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers…}    Subscriber.ts:241

I have tried so many different security configurations but nothing seems to work. I may be doing something wrong... here's my code:

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

public static final String REMEMBER_ME_KEY = "rememberme_key";

public SecurityConfig() {
    super();
    logger.info("loading SecurityConfig ................................................ ");
}



@Autowired
private RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private AccessDeniedHandler restAccessDeniedHandler;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationFailureHandler restAuthenticationFailureHandler;






@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/","/client/**","/systemjs.config.js","/index.html");
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("test").password("test").authorities("ADMIN");

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .headers().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/failure").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .accessDeniedHandler(restAccessDeniedHandler)
            .and()

        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
            .successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler)  
            .failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler) 
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll()
            .and();


}
}
```

**login.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Login service initialized...')
}


loginUser(data) {
    var headers = new Headers();  
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');

     return this.http.post('/authenticate', JSON.stringify(data), { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json());

}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent {

username:String;
password:String;
data:any
constructor(private LoginService: LoginService) {

}


 loginUser(event) {

    this.data = {
  username: this.username,
  password: this.password
};

       this.LoginService.loginUser(this.data).subscribe(data => {

            this.username = '';  
            this.password = ''; 

        });

 }
```

**login.html**

```
<form class="container col-md-8" (ngSubmit)="loginUser()" style="margin:15px 15px">
<div class="row">
<div class="form group col-md-2 parent ">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning centerV_element">Log In</button>
</div>
<div class="form group col-md-3 parent" style="margin:3px 3px">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" class="form control" placeholder="username">
</div>
<div class="form group col-md-3 parent" style="margin:3px 3px">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" class="form control" placeholder="password">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are sending the user and password as json and I think spring security is expecting a form urlenconded. You need to write a security filter to parse your json object, or just try sending data instead of JSON.stringify(data).

Comment: thank you sir, you were right !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure Spring security for Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210128/configure-spring-security-for-angular-2)